# Predict the trajectory of a ping pong ball in 2D with OpenCV [C++]

Tags: c++, opencv, prediction

I'm trying to make the basic robot arm which can hit the ping pong ball using OpenCv and C++.
I managed to detect the ball and move the robot arm according to XY coordinates using inverse kinematics, but now I need to hit the ball, and that's a hard thing.

I thought that if I'll predict the trajectory of the ball, the things would be easier, but unfortunately, this part doesn't seems easy to me either.

I thought that trajectory equations would be a good way to start, so I measured the distance of the ball between 2 frames, also I found the time between those, the angle between table and ball when the ball hits the table, but I don't know how to predict the future trajectory (or how to implement in C++) and I need some help with this.

Also, if you know any way to hit the ball in 2D it would help me a lot.
Thanks!

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7014400/ does it help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! 
Unfortunately, there is to much theoretically content, I need some example, maybe a piece of code / pseudo code to understand how the theory is used in program.

Comment: well, to start with they are using 3 cameras, my guess is to avoid the risk of flattening in 2D the 3D trajectory.

Comment: "2.3.2. Calculation of 3D Location
As shown in Figure 6, the location of the target object can be obtained when it is within view of the two cameras." It seems to me that one camera is not enough to correct estimate the 3D position of the ball

Comment: Yes, but i want to do all the project in 2D, not 3D, so if I use one camera I can obtain the XY coordinates and other parameters like velocity, angle between ball and table and so on. 

I just want a basic hit when the ball goes in the front of the robot and i assume that one camera is enough for this. (side view)

Comment: https://ibb.co/f0T64BQ

I want to know how my robot arm can hit the ball and how can I find the hitting point knowing the velocity, the distance and the time between the first 2 frames (when the ball is landing from the table).

Also, some code would be helpful.